# Access to Sqlite database during create docker app using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, docker, .net-core

I have a .NET Core app that is using Entity Framework with a Sqlite database.

Right now, the app is creating the database using name in `appsettings.json` during startup of the application.

I want to use previously created database file (with `.db` extension). I copied database file to app, changed name in `appsettings.json`.

This file is a fully created database. I copied it from running docker container.

But when I run docker-compose image, then app is started, but database file are overwritten.

How I can omit creating database process and use previously created database?

This is my docker-compose file. Frontend part is omitted due to backend tests

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  backend:
    build: './backend'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - gateway
    environment:
      - Logger:FilePath=//logs//logs.txt
      - Database:Name=Data Source = ./database.db
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /Users/grzegorzogrodowski/Desktop/logs
        target: /app/logs/
  #frontend:
  #  build: './frontend'
  #  depends_on:
  #    - backend
  #  ports:
  #    - "4200:4200"
  #  networks:
  #    - gateway

networks:
  gateway: {}
```

Comment: Please share your docker-compose file.

Comment: @michalk docker-compose added

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'docker-compose down --rmi all' command because it will erase the saved image and when you run the docker-compose up command it will upload another image with the new data.